# Cut a convex polytope in $2^n$ parts

Tags: geometry, polytopes

I have a convex polytope $P$ in $R^n$. I cut it with $n$ orthogonal hyperplanes, each one passing through the center of gravity,, thus obtaining $2^n$ polytopes. W.r.t. the measure (volume) of $P$, what is the measure of the largest cut?

In $n=2$, it is easy to see that the largest cut can almost attain half of the area (instead of a quarter for a perfect cut). What about higher dimensions?

Comment: Is this a "minimum of the maximum" thing? Because for $n=2$ hyperplanes, it seems like cutting near the corner of a cube could get get as close as you like to $100\%$ of the volume.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that every cut passes through the center of gravity. I'll edit

Comment: Taking our polytope to be a hyperrectangle $\displaystyle \prod_{i = 1}^n [a_i, b_i]$ in which one interval is much larger than the others, the $n = 2, 3$ cases suggest (if my visualization is correct!) that we can obtain nearly $\frac{\operatorname{vol}(P)}{2^{n-1}}$ for the volume of the largest piece, but I have no idea if we can get more than this. I should also ask: Are we allowed to choose the polytope? I suppose so, otherwise a cube would be problematic...

Comment: Well in dimension 3 I can see such a cut, and it gives almost half the volume for the largest parts... Imagine a parallelepiped which is very large in the (1,1,1) direction and very narrow in the perpendicular directions. Now cut it with the canonical planes x=0, y=0, z=0. The section contained in $x>0,y>0,z>0$ can almost attain half the volume.

Comment: Well this actually answers my question, looking at this example in $n$ dimensions...

Comment: Ah, yes, take the longest side to protrude directly into one of the orthants, nice! It looks like that works, well done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making an answer out of Tal-Botvinnik's comment.

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, consider an elongated cylinder of radius $r > 0$ and height $h$, with $h$ much bigger than $r$. If $d = (1,1,1)$ is the direction of the height and $V$ the volume of the cylinder intersected with the corresponding quadrant, you can find the simple bound
$$
V \geq \pi r^2 (h/2 - \sqrt{3}r).
$$
For a fixed volume of the cylinder, as $r\rightarrow 0$, $V$ tends to half the volume of the cylinder.

The same argument works in $\mathbb{R}^n$, replacing $\pi r^2$ by the area of a disk of radius $r$ and $\sqrt{3}$ by $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Hi, ok, take the points :-)